# python pool doesnt run function by each item in a list

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I tried to use pool for multiprocessing purposes. check my code:

```
def func1(x):
    print x
if __name__ == "__main__":
    myList = ["111","222","333","444"]
    p = Pool(processes=4)
    res1 = p.map(func1,myList)
```

what I think the export must be:

```
222
111
333
444
```

what it gives:

```
3332
122411
44
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: nothing.. They all print *quasi-simultaneously* and that is the result you get.. Why do you think that the result should be the one you posted? Especially with the `'222'` appearing before the `'111'`?

Comment: first thanks then I edited the post. because each item in mylist should go through the function separately and then the function print it out. and they are not in order because its multiprocessing and each process can be finished before the others. the second part is not my problem anyway. why pool is multiprocessing each letter instead of each item in the list?

Comment: It is not processing each letter instead of each item. This is what happens when you call `print`s from separate worker processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is nothing wrong with your code; it does exactly what should be expected of it.**

What probably confuses you if your belief that *no matter what executes firsts, it should block all others until it is finished*. This is thankfully not true because if it were, it would not be parallel programming. You are launching 4 parallel processes that all write to the standard output (`stdout`) with no regard for precedence and thus you create some kind of race condition that is arbitrarily resolved.

Try writing to 4 separate files instead of stdout (see code below) and you will see the results of parallel code more clearly; the files are generated *simultaneously* instead of in series.

```
def func1(x):
    with open('file_{}'.format(x), w) as f:
        f.write(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myList = ["111","222","333","444"]
    p = Pool(processes=4)
    res1 = p.map(func1,myList)
```

Comment: I want to use requests in pool. how do u suggest it? I want to get an api result which is a json file by requests and store them(json of each domain) in different files. it gets a list and get result for each domain and writes a json file .

Answer (score 1):

As Kounis said in the comment, `Pool` creates a set of processes for async tasks processing. Also, [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) of `Pool.map` explicitely says that processing would be *parallel*.

In practice, since you are creating a `Pool` with 4 worker processes, when you post the `map` of 4 elements, each one of them gets processed immediately by one worker. Therefore, the `print x`s get executed simultaneously.